# Simply count one-to-many

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the number of hits per country in my database,
which has the following tables:

```
mysql> use DB; show tables;
+--------------+
| Tables_in_DB |
+--------------+
| Hits         |
| Tags         |
| HitTags      |
+--------------+
```

And here are some example columns from those tables:

```
mysql> select * from Hits;
+---------+----------+--------------+
| HitID   | HitDate  | HitText      |     
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 0123456 | 01/01/12 | access page1 |
| 7890123 | 01/02/12 | access page2 |
| 4567890 | 01/03/12 | access page3 |
+---------+----------+--------------+

mysql> select * from Tags;
+-----------+---------+---------+
| TagID     | TagType | TagText |     
+-----------+---------+---------+
| 123123213 | country | USA     |
| 456456456 | country | Brazil  |
| 789789789 | country | China   |
| 012345678 | city    | London  |
+-----------+---------+---------+

mysql> select * from HitTags;
+---------+-----------+
| HitID   | TagID     |
+---------+-----------+
| 0123456 | 123123213 |
| 7890123 | 456456456 |
| 4567890 | 789789789 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to fetch the number of hits per country,
such as in the following SQL query {and pseudo code}:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TagText, TagID FROM Tags
    WHERE TagType = 'country';

for each $row {
    SELECT COUNT(HitID) As HitCount FROM HitTags
        WHERE HitTags.TagID = $row[Tags.TagID];
}
```

I have no issue doing this when using separate queries,
but I am sure there is a way of doing this more elegantly
(i.e. using a single SQL query instead of one-per-country).

Maybe using a JOIN, maybe using the ANY keyword.
Or maybe using some nested SELECT statements?

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(HitID) AS HitCount, TagText FROM HitTags
    JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagID =
    ANY (SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE TagType = 'country');
```

But that returns a single row with the total of all hits (from everywhere, although a country is listed along with the result).

Ideally, the result would be something like:

```
+---------+----------+
| TagText | HitCount |
+---------+----------+
|     USA |     1234 |
|  Brazil |     5678 |
|   China |     9012 |
+---------+----------+
```

I know this must be quite common (as in "yeah, I saw this in MySQL class 101")...

I searched the web a lot, but everybody seems to be using a single table (instead of three). I'm really no good with those "one-to-many" relationships. Sorry to be such a newbie!

Any idea, hint or advice would be useful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(HitID) AS HitCount,
  TagText 
FROM HitTags
  JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagID =
    ANY (SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE TagType = 'country')
GROUP BY TagText;
```

Actually, this is better with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(HitID) AS HitCount,
  TagText
FROM 
  Tags 
  LEFT JOIN HitTags ON Tags.TagID = HitTags.TagID
GROUP BY TagText
```

Comment: Great answer! Just for the record, I finally used an INNER join (instead of a LEFT join) and my resulting query looks like: `SELECT DISTINCT TagText, COUNT(DISTINCT HitID) AS HitCount FROM Tags LEFT JOIN HitTags ON Tags.TagID = LogTags.TagID WHERE TagType = 'country' GROUP BY TagText;`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(HitID) FROM HitTags WHERE TagID = t.TagID ) AS hit_count 
FROM Tags t WHERE TagType = 'country'
```

This would do the same but I think is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT COUNT(HitID) AS HitCount, TagText FROM HitTags
JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagID =
ANY (SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE TagType = 'country')
group by TagText
```